# OpenGL ES 2.0 - How to realistically deform a sphere?

Tags: 3d, opengl-es-2.0, game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I want to design a 3D physic engine for an Android Application. I am using OpenGL ES 2.0.

This is what I want to do :

Let's say I have a sphere at the center of my device's screen. Suppose the sphere is filled with water (like a water balloon). Because of the gravity, we expect the sphere to be deformed at the bottom. Furthermore, using the accelerometer of my phone, I can shift the gravity, thus changing the deformation of my sphere.

I have made a lot of research, but I still have no idea how to do that. I don't think it's something very hard to do, but currently the only way I can think of how to do that would be to manually draw, frame by frame, the different shapes.

Is there a way of generating the deformation, instead of drawing it 'by hand' ? Maybe by using shaders ?

I'm completely lost right now !

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in 3D, in a realistic way - then it has nothing to do with OpenGL ES, and would require an advanced physics engine. Shaders would only be used to render the results.

Unless what you need is a simple deformation of the 2D picture of a 3D sphere, frankly, judging from the way you ask the question - it is too hard for you.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there any physics engine in android with soft body dynamics ?

Answer (score 0):

There are good example programs that do deformed spheres and other shapes in the PowerVR SDK for OpenGL ES:

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp

The best free tool for creating animated deformed sphere models on a workstation is Blender

http://www.blender.org/

Comment: In fact I do all my modeling with Blender, using soft bodies dynamics. But is there a way to export the dynamics I have in Blender within my Android Application ? Can PowerVR do that ?

Comment: The PowerVR SDK has the PVRTools library which can read and parse your geometry with textures and simple animations from POD files, which can be exported from Blender directly or through Collada.  I don't think physics or bones are supported, however.